# cannot use c.productService.FindAll() (value of type []service.Product) as []Product value in return statement

Tags: go

I'm trying to implement service and controller layers in my gin api. but I'm getting the above error in my findAll method in controller. what am I doing wrong? what should be the return type of the controller method?

controller:

package controller

```
import (
    "gin-api/service"
)

type Product struct {
    Code  string
    Price string
}

type ProductController interface {
    FindAll() []Product
}

type productController struct {
    productService service.ProductService
}

func New(productService service.ProductService) ProductController {
    return &productController{
        productService: productService,
    }
}

func (c *productController) FindAll() []Product {
    return c.productService.FindAll()
}
```

service:

package service

```
import (
    "gorm.io/driver/postgres"
    "gorm.io/gorm"
)

type Product struct {
    Code  string
    Price string
}

type ProductService interface {
    FindAll() []Product
}

type productService struct {
    products []Product
}

func New() ProductService {
    return &productService{}
}

func (service *productService) FindAll() []Product {
    dsn := "host=localhost user=xxx password=xxx dbname=crudapi port=5432 sslmode=disable"
    db, err := gorm.Open(postgres.Open(dsn), &gorm.Config{})
    if err != nil {
        panic("failed to connect database")
    }
    db.AutoMigrate(&Product{})
    var product []Product
    db.Find(product)
    return product
}
```

Comment: *"what am I doing wrong?"* -- the types `Product` declared in package `service` and `Product` declared in package `controller` are two **distinct** types. That means they are NOT **identical**. That means that you cannot use one in place of the other.

Answer (score 0):

You have two `Product` types declared in two different packages, The method `FindAll` in your controller package is expected to return `[]controller.Product` but you are returning `c.productService.FindAll()` which return type is `[]service.Product`

It's better to define a `Product` model in a standalone package and use it as a centralized type.

For declaring models using gorm:

https://gorm.io/docs/models.html#content-inner